# Keras ImageDataGenerator method flow_from_directory

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, keras

I have a question concerning the flow_from_directory method of the `ImageDataGenerator` module. My labels are 2D images so I need to generate augmented data with the same transformation for both images and masks.
Reading the [Keras Image data preprocessing
documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/), it looks like `flow_from_directory` accepts only images in a few formats (PNG, JPG or BMP). What about `.mhd` images or a numpy array? Can I feed them to this module?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flow_from_directory` is going to read the images using PIL ([see here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/image.py)), so Keras can read all the formats supported by PIL.

However, I didn't see any method to read both masks and images at the same time, and perform the same transformations. I am afraid that you will have to create your own ImageDataGenerator. It's pretty straightforward if you start with the current code.

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn´t the last example here [https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/] work in order to apply the same transformation?

Comment: Yes, my bad. When you give the same seed, the operations are the same. So it's a good trick to have one implementation of the DataGenerator make the same operations.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use ImageDataGenerator for any augmentation tools and then use .flow() instead of .flow_from_directory() . this is a cool way for managing images in numpy array format.
chek this out:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255,
                                   rotation_range=40,
                                   width_shift_range=0.2,
                                   height_shift_range=0.2,
                                   shear_range=0.2,
                                   zoom_range=0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip=True,
                                   fill_mode='nearest')
train_generator=train_datagen.flow(training_images, training_labels)
```

That's because numpy array isn't a kind of directory.
So, convert your data set to numpy array format and then try this out. You will get a true result hopefully.